# Wrong(?) type matching in Scala Enumerations

Tags: scala, enumeration

I have an enumeration class for representing types of values. The code of the class is pretty simple:

```
object Type extends Enumeration {
  type Type = Value
  val tInt, tBoolean, tString, tColor, tFont, tHAlign, tVAlign, tTextStyle, tUnknown = Value;

  def fromValue (value:Any) : Type.Type = {
    value match {
      case a:Int                 => tInt
      case a:Boolean             => tBoolean
      case a:Color               => tColor
      case a:Font                => tFont
      case a:HAlign.HAlign       => tHAlign
      case a:VAlign.VAlign       => tVAlign
      case a:TextStyle.TextStyle => tTextStyle
      case _                     => tUnknown
    }
  }
}
```

Where I have the mathing enumerations:

```
object VAlign extends Enumeration {
  type VAlign = Value
  val top, middle, bottom = Value
}

object HAlign extends Enumeration {
  type HAlign = Value
  val left, center, right = Value
}

object TextStyle extends Enumeration {
  type TextStyle = Value
  val bold, italic, regular = Value
}
```

So, why does the following weirdness occur?:

```
scala> Type fromValue VAlign.bottom
res3: Type.Type = tHAlign
```

Also, how can I avoid this weirdness? How can I do type matching from a value to distinguish the different enumerations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you're facing a problem of erased path-dependent types (see also Edit 2 below).

Let's simplify the example first:

```
object Enum1 extends Enumeration {
  val A, B = Value
}
object Enum2 extends Enumeration {
  val C, D = Value
}

def t(x : Any) {
  println(x match {
    case ab : Enum1.Value => "from first enum"
    case cd : Enum2.Value => "from second enum"
    case _ => "other"
  })
}
```

Now, similarly to what you observed, `t(Enum1.A)` and `t(Enum2.C)` both print `"from first enum"`.

What — I originally thought (see edit below) — is happening here is that the `instanceOf` test that results from using the `:` in the pattern doesn't make the difference between the two path-dependent instantiations of `Value`, so the first case always matches.

One way to work around this is to match on the *values* of the enumeration instead of the *type* of these values:

```
def t2(x : Any) {
  println(x match {
    case Enum1.A | Enum1.B => "from first enum"
    case Enum2.C | Enum2.D => "from second enum"
    case _ => "other"
  })
}
```

---

**Edit 1** Actually my hypothesis does not match what the [spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) says. According to the language specification (§8.2 Type Patterns):

> Type patterns consist of types, type variables, and wildcards. A type
>   pattern T is of one of the following forms:
>
> - A reference to a class C, p.C, or T #C. This type pattern matches any non-null instance of the given class. Note that the preﬁx
>     of the class, if it is given, is relevant for determining class
>     instances. For instance, the pattern p.C matches only instances of
>     classes C which were created with the path p as preﬁx. The bottom
>     types scala.Nothing and scala.Null cannot be used as type patterns,
>     because they would match nothing in any case.
> - [...]

If I understand this correctly, the `instanceOf` or equivalent *should* distinguish between the two cases.

---

**Edit 2** Seems to be a consequence of [this issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3815).

Comment: Reading the second link you provided does make it seem as if scala enumerations are buggy. I'm actually considering using java enums due to the current state of things. So, this is not the answer that I hoped for, but at least I know where I am standing now. Thanks!

Comment: On second thought, I'll use a common base class for each enumeration, with objects inheriting from it as the values of the enumeration. The values will register themselves with a companion object of the base class upon their creation. This will allow the type syntax I wanted, along with getting enumeration values.

Comment: @LightningIsMyName the general concensus seems to be that you shouldn't use Enumeration and should use case objects that extend a sealed abstract class instead

Comment: @LuigiPlinge: Funny that you said that, since I just finished writing exactly that (without checking what other people did) and then I saw your comment :) Thanks for confirmation though - now I know I'm on the right track